# Memory leak when comparing large files (under ARC)

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to compare 2 files. When the files are very large (I'm testing with 1,7G) the process grows and grows until it stalls. Obviously ARC is not freeing up space correctly (or the objective-c librarys don't clean up after themselves).

In Instruments I see that "Malloc 4,0KB" has increasingly high Live Bytes - which points directly to NSFileHandle or NSData, as I am using a buffer size of 4096 Bytes.

I have tried a lot of different things already, like initializing the files with every loop and setting them to nil at the end of every loop. Nothing helps.

Any ideas?
Would a NSAutoreleasePool help?

Here's the core code:

```
NSFileHandle *file1;
NSFileHandle *file2;

int bufferSize = 4096;

file1 = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: [self.input1 stringValue]];
file2 = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: [self.input2 stringValue]];

int long long size1 = [file1 seekToEndOfFile];
int long long size2 = [file2 seekToEndOfFile];
int long long pos1 = 0;
int long long pos2 = 0;

if(size1 != size2) {
    NSLog(@"Files have different sizes");
    return;
}

do {

    [file1 seekToFileOffset: pos1];
    [file2 seekToFileOffset: pos2];

    NSLog(@"Reading at: %lli",[file1 offsetInFile]);

    if(![[file1 readDataOfLength: bufferSize] isEqualToData: [file2 readDataOfLength: bufferSize]]) {
        break;
    }

    pos1 += bufferSize;
    pos2 += bufferSize;

} while(pos1 < size1);

if(pos1 < size1) {
    NSLog(@"Files do not match");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Files are an exact match");
}
```

Comment: Insert `@autoreleasepool` in yours loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has happened to me before, after posting the question I had some new idea how to do it.

I used

```
NSData initWithContentsOfFile: options: NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:nil
```

to read the file, instead of NSFile. Now it works.

```
int bufferSize = 4096;

NSData *file1;
NSData *file2;
NSRange range1;
NSRange range2;
unsigned char buffer1[bufferSize];
unsigned char buffer2[bufferSize];

range1.length = bufferSize;
range2.length = bufferSize;
range1.location = 0;
range2.location = 0;

int long long size1 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: [self.input1 stringValue] error:nil] fileSize];
int long long size2 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: [self.input2 stringValue] error:nil] fileSize];


if(size1 != size2) {
    NSLog(@"Files have different sizes");
    return;
}

file1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self.input1 stringValue] options: NSDataReadingMappedAlways error: nil];
file2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self.input2 stringValue] options: NSDataReadingMappedAlways error: nil];

do {
    [file1 getBytes: buffer1 range: range1];
    [file2 getBytes: buffer2 range: range2];

    NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: buffer1 length: bufferSize];
    NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: buffer2 length: bufferSize];

    if (![data1 isEqualToData: data2]) {
        break;
    }

    NSLog(@"Reading: %i",(int)(((float)range1.location / (float)size1) * 10000) / 100);

    range1.location += bufferSize;
    range2.location += bufferSize;

} while(range1.location < size1);

if(range1.location < size1) {
    NSLog(@"Files do not match");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Files are an exact match");
}
```